# Changes to one TextBox also automatically affects another TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I have it so that when changes are made to textbox1 changes will also occur in textbox2?

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
textbox1.TextChanged += delegate { textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text };
```

If that doesn't help you, please give more information.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add an event handler to textBox1.  Double-click on it in the designer: you're now looking at code that will be executed when the text of that textbox changes.

Now type:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

So as you can probably see, when textBox1 changes, the Text of it (value of the Text property) will be transferred to the Text of textBox2.

Hope that helps!